# Gradle - Default build type always debug

Tags: android, shell, build, gradle, release

I have an Android App with build types "release" and "debug"

When I build it with

> ./gradlew build

It always uses the debug build type.

**Why that and how can I choose to build release?**

Comment: There are lots of tasks available beyond `build`, such as `assembleDebug`.

Comment: according to https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html: have you tried to specify your default task by `defaultTasks 'clean', 'run'`?

Comment: thank you, seems to work with assembleRelease and it is somehow much faster than using build

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Android Studio you can change the default executed build type int the left bottom tab called Build Variants. There you can see your app and build types. When you change it for your app and press the execution button, it executes the new default task provided. However, I don't really know how to change the default one using the command line, but you can execute the one you want with the next template:

```
gradle taskFlavorBuildType
```

for example, to build a debug build type it is:

```
gradle assembleDebug
```

You can find more info [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Tasks).

Comment: nope, I´m on a linux machine and build via console. I´ve tried it and it seems to work. Can you tell me why it is so much faster than building with ./gradlew build?

Comment: That is because you are restricting the build. If you execute that you are building all the targets while if you make assembleDebug you are only assembling this